# What owner and mod should I give to /var/www

Tags: permissions, apache2

I would like to be able to edit the source code of my website from my editor and also allow the website to load in the browser. With `sudo chown -R 'www-data':'www-data'`the code is not editable but loads on the browser and with `sudo chown -R 'username':'username'` the other way around.
How can I get both?

Comment: There are so many possibilities and this question has been asked many many times over. Personally I keep those files owned by root and as much as possible ro by www-data, but there are many options and it varies with your use. It this a production or test server ? enable home directories is another option.

Answer (score 0):

First, give the ownership to www-root using the command:

> sudo chown -R 'www-data':'www-data' /var/www

Then, give permissions to group members using the command:

> sudo chmod -R g+rw /var/www

Finally add your username to the www-data group using this command:

> sudo adduser `your_username` www-data

This way, you will be able load on the browser as well as edit the files.